# Mouse keys keypad 5 click not working after ubuntu 22.04.1 upgrade

Tags: accessibility

Upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.1 over the weekend. Checked that Mouse Keys is enabled under Accessibility settings. The cursor movement functions for the keypad number such as 2 and 4 work properly but the 5 button does not produce a mouse click even though the pointer shows as a hand with a finger extended. Rebooting does not fix the problem.

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

You need to log in on an Xorg session for making this work.

**Using GUI**

1. Log out using the "logout" option in the system menu (when you click
   on the combined wifi/speaker/battery icon in the top right.
2. In the login screen, select your username so you could type your
   password
3. Before typing your password, click the cog wheel on the bottom
   right, then select "Ubuntu on Xorg". Now enter your password and log
   in.

**Using CLI**

Open a command liner terminal and use any text editor (We are using vi) and open this file with root permission.

1. `sudo vi /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
2. Look for the line that says `"WaylandEnable=true".` Change it to `"WaylandEnable=false"`.
3. Now restart the GDM3 or reboot your desktop.

$ `sudo systemctl restart gdm3`

4. To check the current version, run this code in the Terminal:

   echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE

Comment: Thanks!  As it happens, the problem went away with 22.04.2.  Perhaps because I first followed your advice and then switched back to regular Ubuntu?

Comment: @user5868557 I did a fresh install of 22.04.2 and I had to do the procedure of my answer.

Comment: I have 22.04.3 and if I press 5 on the keypad after enabling mouse keys, I often get a right click instead of left one (deterministic, when it starts then it'll always produce right clicks). That's so strange, I can't find any piece of configuration about this in `dconf-editor` or anywhere else.

Comment: @Avio , try pressing "/",  "*"  "-"  "+" and  "." . One of them change 5 to right and left click.

Comment: @VitorAbella, you were totally right, it's ```/``` that makes ```5``` change mode from left click to right click, thanks!